# Centering just one line in a multi-line caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

There are multiple questions already answered for centering an entire caption, but my problem is that I wish to just `\centerline` or `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` just one line in a multi-line caption.

For example (I am using the `\ce` package for chemistry) if I were to write the following:

```
\caption{In the presence of A and B, C will be generated:

\centerline{ \ce{A + B -> C}.}

}
```

Will just error out on me.

Comment: An error here may be due to the fact that you're supplying a paragraph break which ends up in the LoF. Instead, supply a short optional LoF caption and include the rest of your code as-is: `\caption[<LoF>]{<long caption>}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
\caption[Short caption needed.]{In the presence of A and B, C will be generated:
\[ \text{\ce{A + B -> C}.} \]
}
```

The most convenient way how to center an equation is to use the `equation` more, which is done by `\[..\]`. However, you can't bring that to the list of floats, because that causes errors, well, you don't want the equation on display in the list of floats, do you? So the short caption is the solution.

Comment: The ones that are fragile and get robustifyed by fixltx2e are `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: ah ok. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 3):

You should put a version for the list of figures file as an optional argument. Since I don't know what package `\ce` comes from, I can only suggest a possibility:

```
\caption[In the presence of A and B, C will be generated: \protect\ce{A + B -> C}.]%
{In the presence of A and B, C will be generated: 

\centerline{ \ce{A + B -> C}.}}
```

The problem stems from `\addcontentsline`, which is used to write the caption to the list-of-figures file. This command does not allow new paragraphs (blank lines). If an optional argument is supplied, then `\addcontentsline` uses that argument.

Note: `\caption` firsts typesets its argument in an `\mbox`. In that setting, blank lines are ignored (as are the `$$` for display math encountered in `\[` and `\]`). Only if this results in a line too long does it switch to typesetting in a `\parbox`. Since `\centerline` produces a box as wide as a line, this forces the second method. But `\[...\]` does not.